# How to prevent "missing use strict" at end of IIFE assigned to variable?

Tags: javascript, jshint

Using jshint, if you have something like:

```
var Thing = (function(){
    "use strict";
    // code and stuff...
}());
```

I get a "missing use strict" error on the last line. I suppose this is because the `var Thing =` falls outside of the strict scope. Is there a way to prevent this warning without turning off the use strict warnings entirely?

Comment: Can you paste your .jshintrc ?

Comment: {"browser": true,
  "esnext": true,
  "globals": {},
  "globalstrict": true,
  "quotmark": false,
  "undef": true,
  "unused": true}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .jshintrc, remove `globalstrict: true` and use `strict: true` http://jshint.com/docs/options/#strict

`globalstrict` is for file scope 'use strict' and `strict` is for fonction scope (the one you want).

Answer (score 1):

You can use one more wrapper:

```
(function(namespace) {
   'use strict';

   namespace.Thing = (function() {
     // code here
   })();

})(window);
```